# I am getting weird pointy edges

Tags: vertices, subdivision-surface, shader-nodes

So, the thing in simple words is, I cannot even think of the right word to describe this, but like this simple wave texture will end up making the sphere with these weird pointy vertices, how do I get rid of these?
Please try to suggest an efficient answer coz my GPU is a poor 1650Ti.
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your base mesh, but my guess is that it isn't sufficiently subdivided. Add a _Subdivision Surface_ Modifier and see if that helps. Also, the primitive UV Sphere is not ideal for displacement, as it has tri's at the "poles". A good way to make a quad-based sphere is to start with a cube, add and apply a _Subdivision Surface_ Modifier level 2 or 3 or so, then add and apply a _Cast_ Modifier set to sphere (default) with the _Factor_ set to 1. Then add another _subdivision surface_ (this time don't apply) at level 3 or 4 to see the displacement properly.